# Foundation Grid putting small panels before larger panels

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to create a visual only (no text, except for captions) style webpage.

To give this page the best look, I want each clickable box to be a different size.

Here's what i want.

```
__________________________
|                 |   2   |
|         1       |_______|
|                 |   3   |
|_________________|_______|
|_4_|_5_|        8        |
|_6_|_7_|_________________|
```

So far, i've got boxes 1,2 and 3. The problem I'm having is with 4,5,6 and 7. Because they are smaller than box 8, instead of what I want, I get them displaying like below, which breaks flow, leaves blank spaces, and extends the page further than one screen.

```
|_4_|_5_|_6_|_7_|
|        8        |
|_________________|
```

How do I format the code so the layout is as I want it?

My code is below, all foundation framework is standard.

```
<body class="blackbackground">
<div class="fixed" id="includeHeader"></div>
  <div class="fullwidth row collapse">
    <div class="large-8 medium-12 relative columns">
        <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
            <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
               <h2 class="brighten">Portfolio</h2>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-12 relative columns border">
         <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
            <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
                <h2 class="brighten">Contact</h2>
            </div>
         </a> 
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-12 relative columns border">
         <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
            <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
                <h2 class="brighten">r3gamers.com</h2>
            </div>
         </a> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="fullwidth row collapse">
    <div class="large-8 medium-12 relative columns">
        <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
            <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
               <h2 class="brighten">Portfolio</h2>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-12 relative columns border">
         <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
            <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
                <h2 class="brighten">Contact</h2>
            </div>
         </a> 
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-12 relative columns border">    
        <div class="fullwidth row collapse large-4">
            <div class="fullwidth row collapse large-4">
                <div class="large-6 medium-6 relative columns border">
                  <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
                      <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
                         <h2 class="brighten">About Me</h2>
                      </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="large-6 medium-6 relative columns border">
                  <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
                      <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
                         <h2 class="brighten">About Me</h2>
                      </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fullwidth row collapse large-4">
                <div class="large-6 medium-6 relative columns border">
                  <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
                      <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
                         <h2 class="brighten">About Me</h2>
                      </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="large-6 medium-6 relative columns border">
                  <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
                      <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
                         <h2 class="brighten">About Me</h2>
                      </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>




<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a document to answer my question. The problem was that I wasn't splitting the 4-row section containing 4,5,6,7 into two rows. As such, i was adding 6 and 7 after 4 and 5, or in the next row within the flow of the webpage, not within it's own little section. The fixed code is added below, as well as the webpage which guided me to the correct answer. (the lesson should be included in the documentation really).

```
  <body class="blackbackground">
<div class="fixed" id="includeHeader"></div>
  <div class="fullwidth row collapse">
    <div class="large-8 medium-12 relative columns">
        <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
            <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
               <h2 class="brighten">Portfolio</h2>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-12 relative columns border">
         <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
            <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
                <h2 class="brighten">Contact</h2>
            </div>
         </a> 
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-12 relative columns border">
         <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
            <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
                <h2 class="brighten">r3gamers.com</h2>
            </div>
         </a> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="fullwidth row collapse">
      <div class="large-2 columns">
          <div class="row">
              <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
                <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
                   <h2 class="brighten">About Me</h2>
                </div>
              </a>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
                <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
                   <h2 class="brighten">About Me</h2>
                </div>
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="large-2 columns">
          <div class="row">
              <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
                <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
                   <h2 class="brighten">About Me</h2>
                </div>
              </a>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
                <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
                   <h2 class="brighten">About Me</h2>
                </div>
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="large-8 columns">
          <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
            <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
                <h2 class="brighten">Contact</h2>
            </div>
         </a> 
      </div>
  </div>      

<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

https://zurb.com/university/lessons/how-to-bridge-rows-in-foundation